# Widget and OpenGl

Tags: opengl-es

I want to make ball collision with camera bounds. Does OpenGL ES api have some functions that returns camera positions?

Comment: There is no such concept as a camera in OpenGL. You can however write one yourself to simulate a virtual camera. There are plenty of tutorials online.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenGL ES (and Desktop OpenGL) don't have any concept of camera, so, no API for camera positions.

A camera is just a matrix transformation.